# Get UIPanGesture Distance Of A Swipe

Tags: objective-c, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am looking to get real time swipe data as a user swipes across the screen. Here is my code:

```
-(void)initViewWithCIImage:(CIImage*) ciImage UIImage:(UIImage*)uiimage
{
    _originalUIImage = uiimage;
    _originalCIImage = ciImage;
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    _currentCGImageRef = [context createCGImage:_originalCIImage fromRect:[_originalCIImage extent]];
    _picture.image = uiimage;
}

-(void)swipeRecognized:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe
{
    CGPoint startLocation;

    if (swipe.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        startLocation = [swipe locationInView:self.view];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"start loc is %f",startLocation.x);
        CGPoint stopLocation = [swipe locationInView:self.view];
        CGFloat dx = stopLocation.x - startLocation.x;
        CGFloat dy = stopLocation.y - startLocation.y;
        CGFloat distance = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy );
        NSLog(@"Distance: %f", distance);
    }
}
```

When I begin the swipe, I get a valid distance point. However as I continue to swipe I get distance is infinite:

Here is a log print out of my code:

2014-09-23 17:06:57.735 CameraApp[2503:60b] startLocation.x is -0.000000

2014-09-23 17:06:57.738 CameraApp[2503:60b] Distance: 856.214417

2014-09-23 17:06:57.739 CameraApp[2503:60b] startLocation.x is -413119666577672720342843392.000000

2014-09-23 17:06:57.740 CameraApp[2503:60b] Distance: inf

....repeats last 2 lines as I swipe

Can you think of why I am getting infinite or how I can set my code up better to get real time swipe distance data?

Thank you!

Comment: `startLocation` is a local variable. In gesture states other than "Began" you don't initialize `startLocation`. You should make it an instance variable.

Comment: Massive derp! Thank you.

Put it as an answer and I'll give you full credit. I was way too deep and not paying attention to the fundamentals! Thanks for the fresh eyes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startLocation` is a local variable. In gesture states other than "Began" you don't initialize `startLocation` leading to strange values. You should make it an instance variable.